# Problem referencing websites

Tags: bibliographies

I have a rather specific problem adding links to my list of references. My reference list is basically

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9} % no idea what that 9 does there
\bibitem{something}
    author, title etc
```

The list mostly contains book titles but I have a few links. Including the following works:

```
\bibitem{fips}
FIPS 180-4,
http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.180-4.pdf
```

When I add the following the file won't compile (or whatever it's called):

```
\bibitem{hmac}
FIPS 198-1,
http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips198-1/FIPS-198-1_final.pdf
```

The error message is "missing $ inserted", on the line of the latter link. That doesn't make sense to me. If there's a dollar sign missing somewhere, why does tex complain *only* if I add that last link?

I have no idea how to resolve this weird problem, any advice?

Comment: `\usepackage{url}` and then `\url{http://....}`

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. 

The reason for the strange error is that "_" is a special character, generally indicating a subscript (which is defined in a math environment). The `url` package tells LaTeX how to deal with it when it appears in a URL.

Answer (score 1):

> `\begin{thebibliography}{9} % no idea what that 9 does there`

The argument of `thebibliography` defines the maximum length of the labels. If the labels are automatically generated (e.g., `[1]`, `[2]`, etc.) then the argument  “9” is fine if there are less than ten entries. If you use customized labels (e.g.: `[fips]`) the argument must be the widest label.

If you have very few entries (and then `9` nine is a good argument) really there are nothing wrong with this  manual composition of the bibliopgraphy (apart of using the `url` package as suggested), but otherwise is much better use a BibTeX database using JabRef or a similar program. It is a more complex approach, but you will obtain automatic ordering and  formatting of entries according to predefined styles. See [Managing bibliographies with LaTeX](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-1/tb94mori.pdf) for a more detailed introduction to this approach.